# How to use a .edu domain with WordPress?

Tags: domain

I work with a university that already has a domain name that ends in `.edu` (clari.buffalo.edu).  I want to use this domain name as we have decided to migrate our web page to WordPress. From the [sign up page](http://store.wordpress.com/premium-upgrades/custom-domains/), it appears that `.edu` is not supported.

Is this true? If not, how can I use a `.edu` name with WordPress?

Comment: As per the [WPSE FAQ](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/faq), Questions specific to the wordpress.com hosted service are **out of scope**. Please refer your question to [wordpress.com support](http://en.support.wordpress.com).

Comment: @Chip Thanks for the reply.  This is my first time posting here.  I was unaware of the scope.  Yeah the ? does not fit the scope here.  My apologies.  Unfortunately, support is only for paying customers [(LINK)](http://en.support.wordpress.com/contact/) and I can't pay until I resolve this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you're confusing [`wordpress.org` vs `wordpress.com`](http://en.support.wordpress.com/com-vs-org/). If `wordpress.com` is what you're looking for, this isn't the place. Per the [About page of WPSE](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/about),

> Don't ask about... WordPress.com support issues

Now, if you're referring to using self hosted WordPress (`wordpress.org`) with a `.edu` domain, there are no limitation on domain extensions (afaik) and you should be able to set it up no problem as long as you have:

- Somewhere to host it
- The ability to point your domain to that hosting

For info on setting up self hosted WordPress, read more about [Installing WordPress](https://codex.wordpress.org/Installing_WordPress). The items under [Learn How to use WordPress](https://codex.wordpress.org/) may be helpful for you as well.

Comment: This was great clarification.  Sorry about misunderstanding the purpose of this site but very helpful answer.  I think I want the .org after your redirect.

Comment: @TylerRinker, I've added a link to the official document about Org vs Com.